# Intellij Console does not print foreign words

Tags: java, intellij-idea, utf-8, console

In the main method i have written:

```
System.out.println("австрийскому");
```

And in the terminal I get the output:

```
????????????
```

Why does not Intellij print russian words in the console?

Comment: See https://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to Pasticcio's solution can be found here:

http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/04/i18n-unicode-at-windows-command-prompt.html

Answer (score 1):

the console works in UTF-8, while those russian characters you are trying to print are Unicode/UTF-16.

there is probably not any work around this, if you really need to make logs in russian, make a little JFrame with a JTextArea inside where you print your stuff